# Apricity OS officially dead: how to switch repositories to vanilla arch?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

*Apricity OS* is now [officially dead](https://apricity-os.github.io/).

How can I safely remove Apricity custom repository without breaking the update process and preserve packages installed from apricity-core repository (*yaourt*, *google-chrome*, etc) and switch to vanilla Arch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that simply removing the apricity-core repository from /etc/pacman.conf solves my issues.
pacman uses packages from other repositories (if available). I.ex.: google-chrome switched automatically to aur.

Comment: Thank you, add more tutorial to keep it up-to-date if possible for you